# Scrolling an element horizontally using JQuery on mouse scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I have a simple image gallery [here](http://tarashish.com/instagreat). All I want to do is to scroll through the list of images when the user scrolls his mouse.

Any ideas ? `$('').scroll()` definitely doen't work. Even if i bind it to the window by

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  //do something
});
```

It doen't work , because my window has too less height to be scrollable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not jQuery, but there is a pure JS plugin to capture the mouse scroll event:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/javascript-mouse-scroll-event-down-example/

demo:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/javascript-mouse-scroll-wheel-event.html